# How can I make You Tube full screen on my iPad when using Safari?

Tags: ipad, safari, youtube

I recently updated my iPad and now if I go to You Tube (i.e., youtube.com) using Safari and try to make a video full screen the navigation bars etc... still take up about 1/5th of the screen at the top.

Is there a way to get it to show the video on the entire screen?

(Note I am not using the You Tube app and I would prefer a solution that doesn't require using it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fullscreen YouTube uses of its website, is not a "real fullscreen" feature. It just maximize the size of the video to the size of the webcontent.

So unlike Vimeo (for example) you won't get a real fullscreen without YouTube updating it's webplayer (or you using the YouTube app) .

Answer (score 8):

Use the 'desktop' mode instead: it's found at the end of the YouTube menu (click on the logo at the upper left).

Comment: Brian de Alwis was correct. The inability to maximize the video is a "feature" of the Youtube mobile site. Use the "desktop" version instead. Don't know why he was downvoted as he was the only one to ptovide a correct answer.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! This is the only answer that worked for me as well.

Comment: This no longer works, as YouTube incorrectly reports that the fullscreen feature "is not supported" on my device (iPad Pro 9.7)

Comment: The menu is now found by clicking the three dots in the top right. I could then choose Desktop which first redirected me to the app and then back to Safari but now to the Desktop version of the site.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem until I started watching the videos through Google videos instead of browsing through youtube. That way even if the video you want to watch is on YouTube you can still make it full screen through Google videos.

Answer (score 1):

Use quietube.com. It embeds any YouTube video with the default player, so the native fullscreen feature works.

You can use their bookmarklet, or just paste the whole YouTube URL after http://quietube.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

Once in the “false” youtube fullscreen, try a two finger swipe, as if zooming in and you’ll get it. It works for my iPad on iOS 11.3.1.

After years the solution came accidentally. I tried to zoom in while in fullscreen like in a video from “Photos”. Once in full screen yo get the 2 buttons for 15”rewind o fast forward. , It was so obvious, having already tapped the “fullscreen” button on youtube, that I hadn’t even thought about. And intuitive, as usual with apple (in case it’s a safari‘s feature.

Answer (score -1):

Mine fixed itself after I installed the you tube app,I watched a few videos on it came back fired up safari forgetting I had installed YouTube app and couldn't full screen well I was full screening wtf.yay.i then deleted YouTube app safari still full screens.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I installed the you tube app and there was no change in Safari.